# SpeechSynthesisUtterance not triggering "mark" events

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

I can't get the [`mark`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/mark_event) event of a [`SpeechSynthesisUtterance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance) instance to trigger.

As far as I can tell, this should work. I expect to see

```
Started
Reached mark
Done
```

Instead, I get

```
Started
Done
```

```js
document.querySelector('#play').addEventListener('click', function speak() {
  const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(
    `<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <speak version="1.1">Foo <mark name="bar" /> baz.</speak>`
  )
  
  const log = document.getElementById('log')

  utterance.addEventListener('start', () => {log.value = 'Started\n'})
  utterance.addEventListener('mark', () => {log.value += 'Reached mark\n'})
  utterance.addEventListener('end', () => {log.value += 'Done\n'})

  log.value = 'Waiting…'
  speechSynthesis.cancel()

  speechSynthesis.speak(utterance)
})
```

```html
<textarea id="log" disabled rows="3">Waiting…</textarea>
<hr>
<button id="play">Speak</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to let you know that it's a bug and that SSML isn't yet implemented.

https://github.com/WICG/speech-api/issues/10
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88072

You'll see that the chronium issue is 9 years old so I doubt it'll be fixed anytime soon.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Thanks for sharing that info.